# calc2.html:19 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in Ошибка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<img class="zobr" src="142035442.jpg" height="500px" width="800px">

<script type="text/javascript">
   var in = '1okno.png';
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.zobr').click(function(){
       $('.zobr').attr('src', in);

       });
   });
</script>
```

Вроде нормально пишу код, делаю переменную, но вот... В чем проблема?

Поправка.. ввожу вместо in - lin и все работает.. что за??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вроде нормально пишу код, делаю переменную, но вот... В чем проблема?
>   Поправка.. ввожу вместо in - lin и все работает.. что за??

Зарезервированное:

> Оператор **in** возвращает true, если свойство содержится в указанном объекте или в его цепочке прототипов.

[С офф. сайта.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

```js
var ine = '//picsum.photos/200/300';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.zobr').click(function() {
    $('.zobr').attr('src', ine );

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="zobr" src="//picsum.photos/500/800" height="500px" width="800px">
```